# I am trying to get xy location using adresseses from south africa in python and geopy

Tags: python, geopy

I am trying to use geopy to extract xy locotions from adresses based in south africa. I am getting the following error message

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'latitude'
```

I tried running the code with one adress at a time and the output in "none". This is my first time using geopy. Here is the code I'm uing

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import numpy as np
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="my-application")
coordinates = []
adresses = ['Voortrekker Street, CBD, Alberton',
       'Cnr Smith & Van der Linde road, Bedfordview, JHB',
       '43 Bradford Road, Eastgate, Bedfordview',
       'Cnr Airport & Heidelberg Roads, Dalpark, Brakpan']
for address in adresses:
    if len(address) != 0:
        location = geolocator.geocode(address)

        lat, lon = location.latitude, location.longitude

        coordinates.append([lat, lon])
    else:
        coordinates.append(["", ""])
        
print(coordinates)
```

Can you help me on how i can fix this. Or maybe other ways to do it?